# How to create multiple REMOTE SQL servers easily?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to create 4-5 REMOTE SQL servers for a learning purposes. I want to avoid all installation, admin, troubleshooting tasks. I want all this FOR FREE.

How do I do this ?

The purpose behind creating these servers is to pull a few tables from the 4-5 servers and put them into another remote server.

Comment: You're obviously aware that setting up servers involves "installation, admin, troubleshooting tasks", not to mention actual hardware and software costs. Why do you expect to get all this for free?

Comment: @Pondlife - For learning some features of SSIS. Don't have access to mulitple servers with some DB to practice what I want to do. Is it possible to run 3-4 VMs on my system and SS inside those and make it look like different servers to my host OS ?

Comment: The simplest approach is probably to install [multiple instances](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143531(v=sql.105).aspx) on one server. Each one is an independent instance of SQL Server so they can all be configured differently, you can stop and start them separately, you can create linked servers between them etc. SQL Express is free, or Developer Edition is cheap (and included in an MSDN subscription) and has all the features of Enterprise Edition. Of course you need hardware capable of running the instances and you may need to restrict their memory usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add remote sql server within same network using the LinkedServer concept

Comment: this post does not work. accepted for points so that i can post images of my problem.